# Firebase batch write non-existent top-level collections

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my Vue3 + Firebase Web-App i have an upload for a .csv that contains students of a school.

The file is read and saved to an object.
Each row of this .csv table has a column called "courseName".
With the click of a button i have a function that uses a for-loop and
firebase batch writing to write the .csv to firestore.

The "courseName" column is important as my firestore structure looks as follows:

```
schools/someID/courses/courseName/students/
```

The function loops through the .csv and adds the lines to a batch write. When courseName changes, the batch is committed, cleared and proceeds to make a new batch for the next students who share the same courseName.

The logic for the batch writing itself looks as follows:

```
const pathRef = doc(db, "schools/" + userInfoStore.userInfo?.schoolID + '/courses/' + currentCourse + '/students/' + val[columnNames.value.UID])

const data = {
    vorname: val[columnNames.value.Vorname],
    nachname: val[columnNames.value.Nachname],
    klasse: val[columnNames.value.Klasse],
    uid: val[columnNames.value.UID]
}

batch.set(pathRef, data)
```

This works, however it leaves the collection with the name of "currentcourse" in italic in the database, which means it does not exist itself and can not be found in a firestore query.

How do i prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works, however it leaves the collection with the name of
> "currentcourse" in italic in the database, which means it does not
> exist itself and can not be found in firestore queue [I guess you mean "query" here].
>
> How do i prevent this?

The easiest way is to materialize these non-existing docs (shown in italic) by creating them with a dummy field. Something along the following lines:

```
const parentPathRef = doc(db, "schools/" + userInfoStore.userInfo?.schoolID + '/courses/' + currentCourse);

const childPathRef = doc(db, "schools/" + userInfoStore.userInfo?.schoolID + '/courses/' + currentCourse + '/students/' + val[columnNames.value.UID]);

const data = {
    vorname: val[columnNames.value.Vorname],
    nachname: val[columnNames.value.Nachname],
    klasse: val[columnNames.value.Klasse],
    uid: val[columnNames.value.UID]
}

batch.set(parentPathRef, {foo; 'bar'});
batch.set(childPathRef, data);
```